# Comparing data for a month across a choice of 2 different years using slicers in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

I am trying to create a tab in Power BI that includes a Year to Year Comparison for a month using a slicer on a date hierarchy, but I'd like the user to be able to chose which years are being compared (for future-proofing the report). This involves using 3 slicers on the report - 2 for the choice of 2 years, and 1 for the month of interest. I haven't yet found a way to get the data to show up for the graph I want.

I created a mock page that displays the type of report I'm looking for, but it only has a month slicer, and utilizes built-in page filters to constrain the years:

[Reference image for what I'd like the graph to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5fki.png)

What I'd like to create is a page with the filter options shown here, but it's not outputting any data, much less anything like the first graph (unless I have both year slicers to be the same):

[Has the slicer options I want, but data doesn't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF0ya.png)

I've looked into including some Time-Intelligent DAX functions, but from what I can tell, nothing seems to be an obvious solution for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Start with two measures - one each for year 1 and 2 - to show the data for those years, and two unrelated slicer tables driving the year selection. Each measure can then pick up its year value (via [SELECTEDVALUE](https://dax.guide/selectedvalue/)) to use for data filtering.

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand your suggestion. To use SELECTEDVALUE, I would point it to the same Year column the slicer is referencing. But there are two separate slicers that both happen to filter the year of the data. If I'm creating two different measures, how do I make it so that it is only affected by one slicer and not the other?

Comment: Hence - Unrelated. Have the two slicers each run over their own Year table(s) NOT connected to the rest of the model. Those tables are there just to provide a list of Year values for the slicers. You can ensure that the tables pickup all available years automatically by making them from via DAX calcs that break data lineage. E.g., `Distinct(Date[Year])`